# Sort two dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to get the shorest distance and its `stop_lat, stop_lon` between the incoming `latD, longD` and the stored one in the `stops` table. I am storing the `lat_stop, lon_stop, distStops` in double tow dimensional arrayList. Currently I am getting this error

- The method min(Collection, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments 
       (List>, new Comparator>(){})
- The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments
    (ArrayList>, new Comparator>(){})

**Example:**

> (140.4, 83.346723, 12.567835),
>
> (90.6, 83.0984543, 10.347291),
>
> (6.4, 83.6453974, 12.570937),
>
> (25.7, 83.198472, 13.7364563)

I want to get this set `(6.4, 83.6453974, 12.570937)`

How can I get the shortest distance and its related `stop_lat, stop_lon`?

I appreciate any help.

```
            // the stops and arrrivaltimes tables exist.

            PreparedStatement preparedLatLong = con
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT lat, longi, name from stops");
            ResultSet rsLatLong = preparedLatLong.executeQuery();

            // ArrayList<Double> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<Double>();
            ArrayList<List<Double>> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();

            while (rsLatLong.next()) {
                double lat_stop = rsLatLong.getDouble("lat");
                double lon_stop = rsLatLong.getDouble("longi");
                double distStops = haversineDistance(latD, longD, lat_stop,
                        lon_stop);
                distanceHistory.add(Arrays.asList(distStops, lat_stop,
                        lon_stop));
                ;


            }
            //Find the shortest diestance and its related longi and lati
            Collections.sort(distanceHistory,
                    new Comparator<ArrayList<Double>>() {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(ArrayList<Double> o1,
                                ArrayList<Double> o2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
                        }

                    }

            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your `distanceHistory` list as `ArrayList<List<Double>>`. This means that each element in this list is a `List<Double>`.

But then, you defined your comparator as a `Comparator<ArrayList<Double>>`. This means that it expects the items it compares to be specifically `ArrayList<Double>`.

When you use `Collections.sort`, it expects a comparator whose base type is *more general* than the base type of the collection. And `ArrayList<Double>` is *not* more general than `List<Double>`.

The simple solution is to change the definition of the comparator to `Comparator<List<Double>>`.

But this design is really not very good. You are supposed to use lists for "similar" things. A list of three doubles that do not represent the same sort of information is not a good design. It would be better to create a small class for this:

```
private static class StopItem implements Comparable<StopItem> {
    double stopLat, stopLon, stopDist;

    public StopItem( double stopLat, stopLon, stopDist ) {
        this.stopLat = stopLat;
        this.stopLon = stopLon;
        this.stopDist = stopDist;
    }

    // Getters, setters...

    @Override
    public int compareTo( StopItem otherItem ) {
        return Double.compare( this.stopDist, otherItem.stopDist );
    }

}
```

You can then create a list of these objects, and use `Collections.sort()` on it, and you don't need an extra comparator.

For example, here is how you'd fill your list:

```
    List<StopItem> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rsLatLong.next()) {
        double latStop = rsLatLong.getDouble("lat");
        double lonStop = rsLatLong.getDouble("longi");
        double distStop = haversineDistance(latD, longD, latStop, lonStop);
        StopItem newItem = new StopItem( latStop, lonStop, distStop );
        distanceHistory.add(newItem);

    }
```

And then you can use `Collections.sort(distanceHistory)`.

Comment: I have added the class `StopsItem`, deleted the ArrayList and am calling this line `StopsItem LLD = new StopsItem(latStop, lonStop, distStop);` after the call of the `distStops` but I dont know how can I use the  `Collections.sort()` and where?

Comment: I have decalred this ArrayList `ArrayList<List<StopsItem>> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<List<StopsItem>>();` before the while statement then I am filling it and I am using it like this `Collections.sort(distanceHistory);` but then I am getting many errors the first one  in the harversine call` lon_stop cannot be resolved to a variable` and the second  at the Collections.sort() line.

Comment: @TheTime I have added some code to my answer to show you how it's used.

Comment: ham and how can I find the related long and lat of this shortest distance?

Comment: Like this `Collections.min(distanceHistory);
    distanceHistory.get(0).getStopLat();
    distanceHistory.get(0).getStopLon();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `Comparator` should take two arguments of type `List<Double>`:

```
Collections.sort( distanceHistory,
                  new Comparator<List<Double>>()
                  {
                       @Override
                       public int compare(List<Double> o1,List<Double> o2 ) {
...
```

since that's type of the elements of

```
ArrayList<List<Double>> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
```

(Does your code even compile as it is?)

Secondly you might want to work on your data structure a bit; perhaps a tuple/class with three attributes rather than just a `List` - right now you're in *object denial* :-) Eg.

```
class MyThingy implements Comparable<MyThingy> {
    Double lat, lon, dist;

    @Override compareTo( MyThingy other ) {
        // implement sensibly.
    }
}
```

Then you can just

```
List<MyThingy> distanceHistory = new ArrayList<MyThingy>();    
...
Collections.sort( distanceHistory );
```

without having to supply an anonymous comparator.

Cheers,

Comment: No my code does not compile since I still have this error in it.

Comment: It seems your IDE has autogenerated the compareTo method for you, and then you changed the signature of distanceHistory()... See above, that should work for you.